# I would like multiple user prompts and for the code to be "written" on multiple lines using line breaks in assending order

Tags: javascript, arraylist, prompt, document.write

I would like it this way as oppose to Alerts which I'm finding is very popular among the coding community. Thank you very much. This is what I have but it is only one box, where I want 3.
Please be kind. :) I'm older and back in school and this stuff isn't like it was ten years ago.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   var string = prompt("Enter three names seperated with a space.: ");
   var textArr=string.split(" ");
   textArr.sort();
     document.write(textArr.join('<br> '));
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're saying. Are you saying you want the user to type into 3 different `prompt` boxes and then display those 3 answers in alphabetical order?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qr15vydp/. What problem specifically are you having?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   var str;
   var textArr = [];
   str = prompt("Enter name no 1: ");
   textArr.push(str);
   str = prompt("Enter name no 2: ");
   textArr.push(str);
   str = prompt("Enter name no 3: ");
   textArr.push(str);
   textArr.sort();
   document.write(textArr.join('<br> '));
</script>
```

If I understand corectly, you need seperate prompts insteed of one.